# Unity: OnCollisionEnter is called more than once in a row for the same object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

It appears that the `OnCollisionEnter` method can be called more than once in a row for the object `A` where the `collision.gameObject` is the same.

What is the logic behind it and why `OnCollisionStay` is not called instead?

There are `CurrentObjectId`/`CollisionObjectId`/`ColliderId`|`CollisionContactsCount` on the log screenshot:

[image]

As you see `OnCollisionEnter` is called three times in a row with the same current and colliding objects without any `OnCollisionExit` calls.

Comment: It looks like it is counting every contact as new collision within the same fixed update frame.

Comment: Why not count it as one collision when it happens within the same frame?

Comment: The thing is that every `OnCollisionEnter` is followed by the same number of `OnCollisionExit` and I can't find a way to determine which `OnCollisionEnter` matches  `OnCollisionExit`. The same problem with `OnCollisionStay`.

Comment: I am not sure why maybe for optimization or it can be useful in some cases. I had problems with these functions too. The way to deal with it would be to add the objects that collided into a list (before checking if it is not already in a list). Remove the object from the list on collision exit. And you could then check if the object is still in the list or not. Not sure about your use case but maybe you can implement something like this.

Comment: Also maybe [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-it-possible-for-oncollisionenter-to-be-called-twice-for-the-same-collision.430847/) will help you.